# Source code for reference for an experienced web developer moving to django

Tags: django

I consider myself an experienced web developer having worked with ASP.Net Webforms & MVC, Symfony and Zend. I also feel right at home with jquery and prototype.

I have for a couple of days been working with a team which is about to start a project on django. I've been looking at python and was thinking about a couple of reference projects to look at before I dive into django. Are there any open source projects / sample code you would recommend? I am looking for projects which are small enough to wrap your head around in a couple of days and intend to use them as a feature walk through of django.

Thanks

Comment: i guess django tutors is good enough: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I've done my fair bit of MVC web apps and am looking for a decently sized app I can read through while I read up these tutorials.

Comment: You can also check http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources#Open-SourceDjangoprojects for open source projects...

Comment: Why not just use the contrib applications that come with django? Reading and understand how apps like the admin, auth and comments work would surely cover vast majority of django's capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at github's [Python page](https://github.com/languages/Python). Many of the projects you will see there should be django-based. I'd suggest picking a few that have many watchers.